# Error in publishing Vue lib as an npm package

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm, monorepo, npm-publish

Is anyone familiar with this monorepo template? I'm confused as to how to deploy the lib folder inside of the packages directory to npm.

what I did was to cd into the `/packages/lib` folder and then run `npm publish` from there. I got this error:
`npm ERR! Cannot set properties of null (setting 'peer')`

What could be the issue? I have reinstalled node_modules but that didn't help

https://github.com/LinusBorg/vue-lib-template